# C++ Starting up different files in if/else if

Tags: c++

```
class Introduction
{
public:
Introduction() 
{
    repeat = false;
  //  Items("/Users/ewokhugz/Documents/Apps/Space Adventure/Space Adventure/CargoItems.txt");
}
~Introduction() {}
void intro_Init();

private:
std::string anyInput();
void invalid();
bool repeat;
};
```

That is my Introduction.h file

This is my Introduction.cpp file.

```
 using namespace std;
 void Introduction::intro_Init () {

//Errors err;

cout << "****************************************" << endl;
cout << "*            Jay: Hey Kid?             *" << endl;
cout << "****************************************" << endl;
cout << "1. Yes? \n2. Ignore" << endl;
string yesOrNo;
cin >> yesOrNo;
if (yesOrNo == "1") {
    //NEED TO INITIATE THE STARTGAME::GAME_INIT()

}
else if (yesOrNo == "2") {
   //NEED TO INITIATE ZERTH
//        Zerth zerthstart;
//        zerthstart.zerth_Init();
}
}
```

I want it so if the user enters 1 then it links to "StartGame.cpp"
and if the user enters 2 then it links to the file "Zerth.cpp"
I've tried everything, and if I run as. If I enter 1 or 2 it'll auto link me to StartGame.cpp.
Many thanks.
**EDIT**
My Intro.h
    class Introduction
    {
    public:
    Introduction() 
       {
        repeat = false;
      //  Items("/Users/ewokhugz/Documents/Apps/Space Adventure/Space Adventure/CargoItems.txt");
    }
    ~Introduction() {}
    void intro_Init();

```
private:
std::string anyInput();
void invalid();
bool repeat;
```

};

My Intro.cpp

```
#include "Intro.h"
#include "StartGame.h"
#include "Zerth.h"
 using namespace std;
void Introduction::intro_Init () {


using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

//Errors err;

cout << "****************************************" << endl;
cout << "*            Jay: Hey Kid?             *" << endl;
cout << "****************************************" << endl;
cout << "1. Yes? \n2. Ignore" << endl;
string yesOrNo;
cin >> yesOrNo;
if (yesOrNo == "1") {
    //NEED TO INITIATE THE STARTGAME::GAME_INIT()
    StartGame gamestart;
    gamestart.game_Init();

}
else if (yesOrNo == "2") {
   //NEED TO INITIATE ZERTH
    Zerth zerthstart;
    zerthstart.zerth_Init();
}
}
```

Zerth.h

```
class Zerth
{
public:
Zerth() 
{
    repeat = false;
    //  Items("/Users/ewokhugz/Documents/Apps/Space Adventure/Space Adventure/CargoItems.txt");
}
~Zerth() {}
void zerth_Init();

private:
std::string anyInput();
void invalid();
bool repeat;
};
```

Zerth.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Zerth.h"
#include "Intro.h"
using namespace std;
void Zerth::zerth_Init () {


cout <<"You are in Zerth" << endl;
repeat = true;
}
```

StartGame.h

```
class StartGame
{
public:
StartGame() 
{
    repeat = false;
   // Items("/Users/ewokhugz/Documents/Apps/Space Adventure/Space   Adventure/CargoItems.txt");
}
~StartGame() {}
void game_Init();

private:
std::string anyInput();
void invalid();
bool repeat;
```

};

StartGame.cpp

```
#include "StartGame.h"
#include "Intro.h"
using namespace std;
void StartGame::game_Init() {
cout << "* Well you've come to the right place. *" << endl;
cout << "* I have a cargo filled with that needs*" << endl;
cout << "* to be shipped.                       *" << endl;
cout << "* Keep in mind that this isn't exactly *" << endl;
cout << "* ... legal bussiness. So keep it quiet*" << endl;
cout << "*   *" << endl;
cout << "* to tell you exactly how I found you. *" << endl;
cout << "* Simply put, I found you under a pile *" << endl;
cout << "* of debris. You were unconcious for   *" << endl;
cout << "* seven or eight weeks after I found   *" << endl;
cout << "* you. Oh! How rude of me, I never     *" << endl;
cout << "* introduced myself. My name is Samuel.*" << endl;
cout << "* This, is my laboratory. I assume that*" << endl;
cout << "* you may have been an assistant of the*" << endl;
cout << "* previous professors? I'll have to    *" << endl;
cout << "* inquire about the accident later. I  *" << endl;
cout << "* didn't quite catch your name, by the *" << endl;
cout << "* way. Also, just to clear some things *" << endl;
cout << "* up... I never quite caught your sex, *" << endl;
cout << "* considering your face is caked in a  *" << endl;
cout << "* layer of dust. No offense, I'd rather*" << endl;
cout << "* know however, if you'd be so kind.   *" << endl;
cout << "****************************************\n\n" << endl;

std::string gender;
repeat = true;
while (repeat == true)
{
    cout << "Gender: " << endl;
    cout << "1. Boy. " << endl;
    cout << "2. Girl. " << endl;

    gender = anyInput();

    if (gender == "1")
    {
        gender = "BOY";
        repeat = false;
        break;
    }
    if (gender == "2" or "girl")
    {
        gender = "GIRL";
        repeat = false;
        break;
    }
    if (gender == "?")
    {
        gender = "HERM";
        repeat = false;
        break;
    }
    if (gender != "?" && gender != "2" && gender != "1")
    {
        invalid();
    }
}

cout << "****************************************" << endl;
cout << "* So you're a " << gender << "!" << endl;
cout << "* So, what was your name?              *" << endl;
cout << "****************************************\n\n" << endl;
std::string name;

cout << "What is your name?" << endl;
name = anyInput();

cout << "****************************************" << endl;
cout << "* Ahh! So your name is " << name << "!" << endl;
cout << "****************************************\n" << endl;

cout << "****************************************" << endl;
cout << "* Let me explain what happened in the  *" << endl;
cout << "* lab while you were out. First and    *" << endl;
cout << "* foremost, I have taken over. I am    *" << endl;
cout << "* your new boss. I'd like for you to   *" << endl;
cout << "* know that the task I have for you is *" << endl;
cout << "* completely unrelated to the reason   *" << endl;
cout << "* that you signed up for your current  *" << endl;
cout << "* position. In the accident, a rare,   *" << endl;
cout << "* unstable compound combined with an   *" << endl;
cout << "* unknown element. In the process of   *" << endl;
cout << "* destroying this entire laboratory,   *" << endl;
cout << "* it has done some interesting things. *" << endl;
cout << "* Come see me tomorrow and I will      *" << endl;
cout << "* explain some more to you.            *" << endl;
cout << "****************************************" << endl;
repeat = false;
//    Player P(name, gender);
//    Pallet_Town pallet;
//    pallet.buildings(true);
}


std::string StartGame::anyInput()
{
using std::string;
using std::cin;

string input;
cin >> input;
return input;

}

void StartGame::invalid()
{
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
cout << "****************************************" << endl;
cout << "*You did not input an acceptable value.*" << endl;
cout << "****************************************" << endl;
repeat = true;
}
```

Ignore the bad story. But yeah here's the code.

Comment: You're not thinking about it correctly. Try to think in terms of "calling a function" and not "linking a file".

Comment: So I would set up StartGame and Zerth as a function?

Comment: That would seem to be a promising direction, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Your files don't execute at run-time: your functions do. Your various files are simply used to organize the various pieces of logic that your game will have.

To do different things based on different user input, create a separate function for each action that you want to perform and then call the right function for the appropriate user choice.

In this case, you may want to have an InitGame() function and a StartZerth() function to handle the yes/no choice of the user.

Once you're done writing your code, you'll run the compiler and the linker (likely through a build command in your IDE) which will produce a binary executable that you can run. By this time, all your files will have been parsed and compiled into the code that actually executes.

Comment: ~Zerth() {}
    void zerth_Init();

Comment: Like that? I created that in Zerth.h. Then in zerth.cpp i void Zerth::zerth_Init () { cout<< "You are in Zerth" << endl; }

Comment: Yes, something like that. Think about it this way: if two users play your game, user A may select `yes` and user B may select `no`. So for one user, one part of the code will execute and for the other user, another part of the code will run. Both pieces need to be compiled into your program so that both pieces can run at any time, depending on user choice.

Comment: Exactly what I am trying to do. And now if the user hits one then I try doing StartGame startgame; startgame.game_Init(); (I have that function already declared in that file, and included) and else if user enters two then Zerth zerthstart; zerthstart.zerth_Init();. But Still no matter what it'll go to StartGame.cpp

Comment: Rather run the StartGame function

Comment: If that's the case you should probably post more code. It sounds as if you already have these two functions defined in two separate classes and you have some code to call one or the other. If that's the case and still only one function is called all the time, it sounds like that's a logic issue in your code.

Comment: Wait, okay. It displays "You are in Zerth" when I hit 2. But then it displays all of the StartGame function as well. Posting Code now.

Comment: Looking through real quick your code seems to be correct. Are you sure you're not explicitly calling your StartGame::gamestart() function from main() as well? It seems to me that this code is ok.

Comment: That's exactly what I was doing. I am an idiot. Thank you so much for your time and help. I got it. (Hopefully). I calling my Start Game and Introduction at the same time.

Comment: An advice, though, regarding the organization of your code: you have multiple copies of the anyInput() and invalid() functions in several classes. That works but you create unnecessary duplication in your program. If these copies of the same function all do the same thing, consider moving them to a common class and make the function a static. You can then call that static function from multiple places without creating an instance of the class that has the function.

Comment: Yeah, I realize it's very unorganized haha. But I am kind of learning as I go with this from a friend I do everything pretty I guess... practical, and then as I go I clean it up more and more. But thank you for the tip.